# android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object

Tags: java, android

I am having an error that I don't know how to fix it
this is what caused it  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
Below is my log cat please help me I need to finish this project and am stuck here

```
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: umo.com.players, PID: 28619
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{umo.com.players/umo.com.players.Home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2868)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
    at umo.com.players.Home.HomeActivity.setupViewPager(HomeActivity.java:195)
    at umo.com.players.Home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:96)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7045)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1653) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is my view pager

```
        private void setupViewPager(){



   final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tournament);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications);
    // tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setText(getString(R.string.fans));

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            int unread = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !chat.isIsseen()){
                    unread++;
                }
            }
                if (unread == 0){
                    adapter.addFragment(new ChatFragment(), "Chats"); //index 0
                }else{
                    adapter.addFragment(new ChatFragment(), "("+unread+") Chats"); //index 0
                }

            adapter.addFragment(new TournamentFragment(), "Tournament"); //index 1
            adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "Home"); //index 2
            adapter.addFragment(new NotificationFragment(), "Notification");//index3
            // adapter.addFragment(new MessagesFragment()); //index 4
            mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: `R.id.tabs` - Does a view with this id exist

Comment: Yes it exists in the XML file

Comment: It was highlighting on the setIcon indicating it will cause a null pointer and the cause was from get tab

Comment: Please help I need to finish this project today

Comment: Post your XML file, please